# ddSlick plugin using Lazyload images

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I need to implement the dropdown list with images, and I encountered [ddSlick plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick), that satisfy my requirements, but my list is big and to load all images require big delay.

I would like to know if there is anyone who has integrated this [plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) with lazyload to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been resolved this problem [see this](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#comment-1715278218)